# How to know the given date is which month's which week?

Tags: ios, objective-c, date

I have a requirement, if I give the specific date, such as:

1. Type in `2016-02-01`, should return `2016-2-1`, means `2016-02-01` belongs to `2016` year's Feb's first week.
2. Type in `2016-09-01`, should return `2016-8-5`, means `2016-09-01` belongs to `2016`year Aug's fifth week.
3. If `2016-01-01` is not Monday, the return year should be `2015-x-x`.

**Attention**,at there the formula mode is from Monday to Sunday is a week.
Such as `2016-04`, `2016-04-04` -> `2016-04-10` is April's first week.`2016-04-01` -> `2016-04-03` is not belongs to April's weeks, it is belongs to March.

I tried using NSCalendar, but the requirement is peculiar, I have no idea deal with it, so, someone could offer some train of thought for this?
Thanks in advance.

---

My tried code:

In my Util.m:

```
+ (NSString *)getCustomMonthAndWeek:(NSString *)formatDateStr {

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    NSDate *date= [[NSDate alloc] init];
    date = [formatter dateFromString:formatDateStr];

    NSCalendar *calen = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

    NSDateComponents *dateCom = [calen components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth |NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:date];

    NSString *ret_str = @"";

    ret_str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%ld-%ld-%@", (long)dateCom.year, (long)dateCom.month, dateCom.weekOfMonth];

    return ret_str;

}
```

In my VC:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *string = [Util getCustomMonthAndWeek:@"2016-04-02"];  // Here prints 2016-4-1, is not my requirement, you see my Attention.
    NSLog(@"%@", string);
}
```

Comment: Can you share with us your current code or whatever you have tried?

Comment: @iOS App Dev, I post my code in my question, at first I use NSCalender , but I found it do not fit my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Using NSCalendar set to NSDateComponents you will find given date is which month's , week . use following code

```
 NSDate *date=[NSDate date];

NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorianCalendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth |NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:date];
```

Components gives output 
    Calendar Year: 2017
    Month: 2
    Leap month: no
    Day: 7
    Hour: 14
    Minute: 55
    Week of Month: 2

Comment: I am sorry man, my test is your train of thought， but you look at my code, and if I type in `@"2016-04-02"`, it will print `2016-4-1`, but it should be `2016-03-weekOf03`. See my requirement.

Comment: you see my Attention,  and my VC's code. my Util's code is similar to your answer, I have make clear the NSCalendar is not fit my question in my post, so I am waiting the answer yet .

Comment: formatDateStr is in string format and it only date format not in date and time format that's the output shows wrong you need to convert formatDateStr into date and time format and after that string format into date and you will get correct output

Comment: formatDateStr = @"2016-02-01 12:53:58 +0000"; like that

Comment: please check date that set to NSDateComponents i think that date is wrong

Comment: please see my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *someDate = // whatever
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *thenComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSHourCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:someDate];
NSDateComponents *nowComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSHourCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
if([thenComponents year] == [nowComponents year] && [thenComponents month] == [nowComponents month] && [thenComponents day] == [nowComponents day] && [thenComponents hour] == [nowComponents hour])
```

{}

Remove the “hour” component if you just want to check the day, or remove both that and “day” (and replace with NSWeekCalendarUnit and the -week method) to check the week.

Comment: The formula mode is from Monday to Sunday.